# How to make useEffect only run once on component mount without lying to React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I want `useEffect` to only run once on component mount, what is the right way of doing it? Check the following example:

```
const UseEffectCounter1 = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {setCount(count + 1)}}>+1</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Re-renders are prevented due to `[]` being passed as dependency array. Code running fine, no errors. 'You clicked 0 times' shows only once, click the button does nothing, which fits the purpose 'only run once on the component mount'.

However this is lying to React and not recommended in Dan Abramov's article [here](https://iqkui.com/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-everything). I should pass the dependency to the dependency array, which is warned as `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'count'`. However if I pass `[count]` in the dependency array, `useEffect` starts updating after component mount.

What is the correct way of making `useEffect` only update on component mount?

Comment: With the example you posted, it would not make any sense to make the useEffect hook depend on the `count`; you should simply have `useEffect(() => { document.title = 'You clicked 0 times' }, [])` so that you have no dependencies and you so not "lie" about it. Could you share the actual scenario, please? It would make easier to understand if and how dependencies should be listed.

Comment: @secan this is the actual scenario, I\m trying to understand useEffect dependency. If there is no sense to make useEffect depend on `count`, why does React give me the warning?

Comment: Because you are making the hook dependent on `count`, so React correctly indicate you are not listing all the dependencies. If you remove the use of `count` inside the `useEffect` and you hard-code the fixed value you want to use, React will stop complaining because you do not have any dependency

Comment: The main goal behind the new react version of hooks lies behind the concept of synchronization and not about the life cycle. 
They are trying to get the mental model for the component, and it's about keeping and thinking the logic in terms of synchronization and not in the lifecycle way. So, we should never thought in mount and unmont way of components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there is no point in making the `useEffect` hook dependent on the `count`, if you are not going to update the title every time the count changes. The code could be:

```
const UseEffectCounter1 = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = 'You clicked 0 times';
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {setCount(count + 1)}}>+1</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Anyway, if you really want to avoid the hard-coded value, you could do something like:

```
const UseEffectCounter1 = () => {
    const initCount = 0;
    const [count, setCount] = useState(initCount);
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = `You clicked ${initCount} times`;
    }, [initCount]);
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {setCount(count + 1)}}>+1</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

As `initCount` is never going to change, the useEffect hook will be triggered only once.